# What is Baire's zero-dimensional metric space?

Tags: general-topology, notation, metric-spaces

I'm not familar with metrizable spaces. I met a notation: Baire's zero-dimensional metric space. Could somebody explain it for me? Thanks ahead:)

Comment: Google reveals [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=ecvd8dCAQp0C&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=Baire%27s+zero-dimensional+metric+space&source=bl&ots=vgMxLm0LxF&sig=fyupxzyazJgrPCRZEGoPClYoTkc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kNp5UeWnFo3K9gSPoIHwBw&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Baire%27s%20zero-dimensional%20metric%20space&f=false).

Comment: Additional context would help, but it's usually this one - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)

Comment: Nice find @DavidMitra. Nagata uses in his book the same notation for this space as the one, which is used in the paper the OP asks about in [his previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373037/what-is-the-topology-the-author-used-which-make-t-is-metrizable/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term almost certainly refers to the product space $\omega^\omega$, the product of countably infinitely many copies of the countably infinite discrete space, which is well-known to be homeomorphic to the space of irrational numbers with the usual topology. More generally, if $D_\kappa$ is the discrete space of cardinality $\kappa$, $D_\kappa^\omega$ is often referred to as the zero-dimensional Baire space of weight $\kappa$.

**Added:** Having now seen your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373037/12042), I’ll add that one can of course replace $D_\kappa$ with any set that has been given the discrete topology, as has been done in that paper that you cite there: in that paper $N(A)$ is the space $A^\omega$, provided that $A$ is given the discrete topology. It is therefore homeomorphic to $D_\kappa^\omega$, where $\kappa=|A|$. All of these spaces are metrizable; I generally define the metric by setting $d(x,y)=2^{-n}$, where $n=\min\{k\in\omega:x_k\ne y_k\}$, if $x\ne y$, and of course $d(x,x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks Brain. Could you tell me what is $A$ in the paper which I cited?

Comment: @Paul: You’re assuming that $X$ has a $G_\delta$-diagonal, so there are open covers $\mathscr{U}_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ as in Lemma $1$. Let $\kappa_n=|\mathscr{U}_n|$ and index $\mathscr{U}_n=\{U_\xi^n:\xi<\kappa_n\}$. Let $\kappa=\sup_n\kappa_n$, and take $A$ to be $\kappa$ with the discrete topology.